# Envelope created is empty

Tags: docusignapi

When i create an envelope using the eSignature REST API, the envelope is created as Draft in Docusign and with no content, as below:

[Docusign draft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9nfJ.png)

[Envelope details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEbI2.png)

But, if i copy the body (json) and paste in postman and if i try to create, usign the DocuSign Rest API Collection, the envelope is created properly and docusign start the worflow automatically.

[Postman Envelope creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjRHY.png)

What i'm doing wrong? There any configuration which i need to setup? Any or suggestion?

Thanks in advance,

Best regards,
Luis Franco

Comment: where is your code? how do you create it the first time when it's empty? you only showed as the postman, but not clear what code you tried

Comment: Pls share your code, otherwise we cant help

Comment: The code is in AL (Dynamics 365 BC programming language).
The code is the following:
[Request](https://imgur.com/a/YmV7f78)

and the request content ( json body) is 
[Request Body](https://imgur.com/DmmfDWg)

When the API is called i get a success response and in the response body i can find the envelopeId returned from the API.
If i go to the DocuSing and complete the Envelope, the system start to send the email and from the 365 BC i can get the new status and download PDF when the document is signed.

Answer (score 0):

What is your envelope ID? Do you see that the envelope is empty after you sign it and download it? or before signing it, when you open the email you find that it's empty?

Comment: Hi, 
I can see the envelope id when i go to Drafts page after log in the Docusign page. If i complete the envelope the Docusign start the workflow and send email to the receipients. After this i can do evertying and it's works properly in my system.

Comment: Hello, is the status sent when you create the envelope? do you mean that when you open the envelope from Drafts you can see it, but when you open it from the email notification it's empty?